# Need an embeddable live polling tool

Tags: looking-for-a-script, embedded-control

We need a live polling tool that can be embedded on a Web page. The key factor is that the polls can be published on demand by a moderator (i.e. the moderator clicks "Publish" or "Go" and the poll is delivered to the end user on the Web page).

Once people answer the poll, the results should be shown in the same window. Then, the moderator can keep publishing more polls in the window.

This should be embeddable within an existing webpage. We started using http://www.coveritlive.com/ but it has restrictions which make it unusable for us (eg: it allows only 6 options per poll question)

Answer (score 1):

There are [quite a number](http://www.google.co.uk/webhp?rlz=1C1SKPM_enGB448GB448&sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=heb&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&rlz=1C1SKPM_enGB448GB448&site=webhp&source=hp&q=free%20polling%20tools&pbx=1&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&fp=cee598fc631c5c56&ix=heb&ion=1&ix=heb&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=cee598fc631c5c56&biw=1920&bih=955&ix=heb&ion=1) of different tools available, here are a few:-

- http://polldaddy.com/
- http://www.micropoll.com/
- http://www.micropoll.com/

There are a couple of decent summary blogs about polling tools [here](http://www.problogger.net/archives/2006/06/02/free-blog-poll-tools/) and [here](http://socialtimes.com/8-free-poll-tools-for-your-website_b5913)